# Modify UIDatePicker selection indicator tint color

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

Is it possible to modify the tint color of a `UIDatePicker`'s selection indicator? Or can it be removed so I can add my own selection indicator image?

I know in the case of `UIPickerView`´s you can disable the selection indicator so that you can provide your own selection indicator image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to change the color of selection indicator by default. 
You can make a workaround though. I would add a simple `UIView` with a color of your choice and alpha value for transparency. Se the size and coordinates accordingly to the original selection indicator to overlay it (size 280x44, coordinates 20/130 for standard picker - not sure about that so find out the right values in case these don't match).

```
UIView *overlayIndicator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 130, 280, 44)];
overlayIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
overlayIndicator.alpha = 0.5f;
[yourDatePicker addSubview:overlayIndicator];
```

Hope it's something you can start with.

[image]

Comment: So there is no way to get rid of the blue selection indicator? Overlaying a red selection indicator over a blue indicator would make it purple then? :-P

Comment: No. Maybe you should consider using an open source/third party date picker or create a customized one? I added a screenshot how a picker from the code snippet looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did with my UIDatePicker that was placed inside a UITableViewCell and sized purely using autolayout constraints. (I recommend subclassing the UIDatePicker).

```
let upperSelectorView = UIView()
let lowerSelectorView = UIView()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        upperSelectorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 127, green: 139, blue: 131, alpha: 0.45)
        self.addSubview(upperSelectorView)

        lowerSelectorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 127, green: 139, blue: 131, alpha: 0.45)
        self.addSubview(lowerSelectorView)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print(self.frame.size.height)
        if (self.frame.size.height == 216) { //height it used in portrait.
            upperSelectorView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 91, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 0.5)
            lowerSelectorView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 125, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 0.5)
        }

        if (self.frame.size.height == 162) { //height it used in landscape.
            upperSelectorView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 63, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 0.5)
            lowerSelectorView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 98, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 0.5)
        }

    }
```

Tested to work on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+.