# Change Selection Indicator of UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I am currently working with a UIDatePicker and am trying to make it look better on a dark background by changing the colors of the selection indicator.

Here is what I have so far:
[image: An image of the current UIDatePicker in action.]

I found a solution of how to apply a new selection indicator to a UIPickerView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466346/how-to-change-the-color-of-uipickerview-selector), but I don't think I have access to the picker view directly.

TL:DR - How do I set the selection indicator to a new image? (Read as white lines instead of black)

Comment: you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599905/modify-uidatepicker-selection-indicator-tint-color

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change UIDatePicker font color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875054/change-uidatepicker-font-color)